# Functions with partial derivatives summing to zero

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0$ at every point. That means $(1, 1, 1) \cdot \nabla f = 0$, where $\nabla f$ is the gradient vector of $f$. I wanted to build a linear map $g: \mathbb{R} ^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ in order to show that $\frac{\partial (f \circ g)}{\partial x} = 0$, but I'm not so sure how to proceed.

Comment: Notice that $x+y+z=0$ is a level surface of the function $f$ i.e. $f(x+y+z=0) = k$. So if you can find a linear $g$ such that $g$ projects every element of $\Bbb{R}^3$ onto that plane, you automatically have that $(1,1,1)\cdot\nabla (f \circ g) \equiv 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a linear function $g$ represented by a constant matrix $G_{a,b}$ so that $g(x)_a \equiv \sum_b G_{a,b}x_b$ and $(f \ \circ g)(x)=f(\sum_b G_{a,b}x_b)$.

You have that $\partial_a ( f \ \circ g)=\sum_{b} G_{b,a}(\partial_b f)=\sum_{b} G^{+}_{a,b}(\partial_b f)$ by the chain rule (note that as a result of the chain rule the gradient transform with the transpose of $G$).

So that in particular if you choose $G$ such that $G_{x,x}=G_{y,x}=G_{z,x}=1$ :

$\partial_x ( f \ \circ g )=\sum_{b} \partial_b f=0$

Comment: Interesting. Is there some idea behind the choice of the matrix or is this really just built to make the result follow? It's not clear to me how this result translates in geometric terms.

Comment: Probably the interpretation is similar to the comment of Ninad Mushi. I just thought that the algebraic approach would have led faster at the solution without too much thinking..